# The onclick in not working with d3.behavior.drag() in Sankey diagram

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

This is the code for the Sankey diagram, The first time I added the this when creating node. It is not working.

```
.on("click", function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    })
```

Then I commented `d3.behavior.drag()`, Then it worked.

This will work.

```
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(energy.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .on("click", function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    });
    // .call(d3.behavior.drag()
    // .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    // .on("dragstart", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
    // .on("drag", dragmove));
```

This will not work.

```
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(energy.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .on("click", function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    })
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
    .on("drag", dragmove));
```

Can someone tell why? How can I add onclick event?

Thanks for your help!!!